# Django Model Choice Field select not working

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have the following form:

forms.py

```
class TipoDePagoForm(forms.Form):
    tipo_de_pago = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=FORMAS_PAGO, required=True)
    folio = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'placeholder': 'Folio',
        'aria-describedby': 'basic-addon2'
    }), required= False)
    medio_venta = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= MediosVenta.objects.all())
```

the ModelChoiceField in HTML is represented like this:

```
 <form method="POST" class="card-body">
              {% csrf_token %}
                <h3>Opciones de Pago</h3>
                  <div class="d-block my-3">
                    {% for value, name in tipodepagoform.fields.tipo_de_pago.choices %}
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                      <input id="{{ name }}" name="tipo_de_pago" value="{{ value }}" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" required>
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{ name }}">{{ name }}</label>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </div>
                  <div class="d-block my-3">
                    <label for="folio">{{ tipodepagoform.folio }}</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="d-block my-3">
                    <select name="{{ tipodepagoform.medio_venta.nombre }}" id="{{ tipodepagoform.medio_venta.id_for_label }}">
                      {% for value, name in tipodepagoform.fields.medio_venta.choices %}
                        <option value="{{ value }}" {% if tipodepagoform.medio_venta.value == value  %} selected {% endif %}>{{ name }}</option>
                      {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                  </div>

                  <hr class="mb-4">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" >Pagar</button>
            </form>
```

when doing the POST in the view (part of the view):

```
def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        today = date.today()
        tipodepagoform = TipoDePagoForm(self.request.POST or None)
        
        

        if tipodepagoform.is_valid():
            tipo_de_pago = tipodepagoform.cleaned_data.get('tipo_de_pago')
            folio = tipodepagoform.cleaned_data.get('folio')
            medio_venta = tipodepagoform.cleaned_data.get('medio_venta')
            print(medio_venta)
```

the form_is is not valid and is giving me the following error:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>medio_venta<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

printing the form I see that is selecting the None value:

```
<tr><th><label for="id_medio_venta">Medio venta:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul><select name="medio_venta" required id="id_medio_venta">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>

  <option value="1">Gimnasio</option>

  <option value="2">Marketplace</option>

  <option value="3">Membresías</option>

</select></td></tr>
```

I don´t know why even if I select any option with a value it does not actually select.

Post print:

```
<QueryDict: {'XXXXXXXXXX], 'tipo_de_pago': ['Efectivo'], 'folio': ['']}>
```

the post is not getting the model choice field

Comment: I am sure, you have an empty request.POST. Please provide us your real html template, i am not sure, that formfield.nombre exists. Probably you mean formfield.name

Comment: I have updated the html showing the complete form, the names are displayed in the html, what I don´t know is why is not being passed once I hit submit, and it is only happening to the model choice field

Comment: i can not imagine why, but you request.post is probably empty. try print(self.request.post) on the first line of post-method. Also you can do: def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        tipodepagoform = TipoDePagoForm(request.POST)

Comment: I have updated it with the print of the self.request.post and is not getting the model choice field value

Comment: ok, can you try <select name="{{ tipodepagoform.medio_venta.name }}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you have a error here:

```
<select name="{{ tipodepagoform.medio_venta.nombre }}"
```

Try to change it on the:

```
<select name="{{ tipodepagoform.medio_venta.name }}"
```